# Get Button from its TabIndex?

Tags: vb.net, variables, button, names

Let's say I have 50 buttons inside a panel. Each of these buttons are automatically assigned an TabIndex number during the design time.
Now what I want to get is the particular button whose TabIndex is 37 and input it to a function `PerformButtonFunction(Button)` that requires a button as its parameter.

Something like this:

```
PerformButtonFunction(Button whose TabIndex is 37)
```

So how do it do it?

Please note: The index need not be 37 every time. The index is obtained through some calculations. Also, the index is not a part of the name of the buttons. I mean the button having the index 37 is not named as "Button37".

Comment: `Me.Controls("Button37")`?

Comment: @GSerg Button having index 37 is not named as "Button37" and the index need not be 37 all the time. I've edited the question please go through it.

Answer (score 2):

```vb
Dim btn = Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button)().FirstOrDefault(Function(b) b.TabIndex = 37)
```

The *First* part allows for there being multiple `Buttons` with that `TabIndex` and the *OrDefault* part allows for there to be none.
Obviously you can use a variable in place of the literal `Integer` in that code.

Answer (score 0):

> You can set button name while creating button dynamically. After that
> you get button by that name.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim index As Ineger = 1
For Each btn In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button)()
    '...
    If index = 37 Then    
    'Call Method here
    Exit For
    End If
index = index + 1
Next
```

Another possible solution could be using the TabIndex which @jmcilhinney already suggested.